# How to dynamically change the name of column to be used for retrieving data

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I want to change the name of the column in my sqlstatement and use it to get its data to be transferred to a ComboBox every time I select an item name similar of the columns on another ComboBox. How to do it?

This is my sample code:

```
        sqlstatement = "select '" & cmbcategory.Text & "' from tblparts"
        Connect()
        command = New MySqlCommand(sqlstatement, connection)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            cmbpart.Items.Clear()
            cmbpart.Items.Add(reader.Item(0).ToString)
        End While
        Disconnect()
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I have updated the post and posted the code.

Comment: `sqlstatement = "select '" & cmbcategory.Text & "' from tblparts"` **never never never never never never never build sql like this!** This is how Sql Injection attacks are used to hack websites http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Oh. Ok sir. I just want to change the column names everytime to be used for reading and get their data to be transfered to a combobox. Is it possible sir? Its for a system project and its an application.

Comment: Chris Marisic is right; what you've done there is a bad habit to get into.  Use parameters, and consider using a stored procedure.  In fact, consider using a command object to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't entirely clear from your question what the problem is, but I suspect that where you have

```
While reader.Read
    cmbpart.Items.Clear()
    cmbpart.Items.Add(reader.Item(0).ToString)
End While
```

you would probably be better off with

```
cmbpart.Items.Clear()
While reader.Read
    cmbpart.Items.Add(reader.Item(0).ToString)
End While
```

Comment: Brian doesn't state what's going on here, having the `Clear() `statement inside the `while` loop will result in the items being deleted every time you add one.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic, thanks for your comment; perhaps I could have been a little less delphic. Your point about SQL injection is a good one, too.